# 11[14761.537078] blk_update_request: I/0 error, dev sdh sector 0 op 0x0: (READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0

Tags: boot

```
[14761.537078] blk_update_request: I/0 error, dev sdh sector 0 op 0x0: (READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
```

[image: 11[14761.537078] blk_update_request: I/0 error, dev sdh sector 0 op 0x0: (READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0]

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Could you [edit] your question so that it's actually a question? As it stands, you're putting 100% of the responsibility of understanding the full context of your issue onto the reader, which means there's an almost-zero chance that someone will offer a solution. The people here are all volunteers, so nobody is required to help if the burden of work is too great.

Comment: We haven't been provided any context, not knowing your OS/release etc.. but you have a hardware issue on device sdh, so have you checked health (*assuming it's a hdd/ssd or device with SMART ie. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools*).  If it's a cheap consumable device (*that has no SMART*) just replace it & restore data from backups.